# Convert Smoothed gaze coordinates to raw gaze coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine, computer-vision, eye-tracking

How can I convert smoothed gaze coordinates (in range [0,1]) to raw gaze coordinates (pixel coordinates) mathematically (I am using Eyetribe eye tracker)? I have tried multiplying smoothed gaze coordinates with the screen resolution but that doesn't work as all points are clustered at one place. 
I want raw coordinates to get a heatmap of gaze locations on the screen for a game.I had built the game in unity3d.

Comment: "Normalised" would probably be a better term here than "smoothed", but nonetheless multiplying "gaze coordinates with the screen resolution" is exactly what you need to do. So you should give more details of how you did this and what you mean by "all points are clustered at one place".

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill I multiplied x and y coordinates with width and length of screen (x coordinate with 1366 and y coordinate with 768).

Comment: @MichaelMacAskill  By clustered I mean that the data after plotting is in range (650<=x<=800 and 350<=y<=450), whereas it should be uniform (uniformly spread on the screen as the data is gaze coordinates of each eye).

Comment: The question is whether the clustering is non-physiological. Gaze is never distributed uniformly, and is often clustered near the centre of the screen, although this of course, highly task dependent. Do you see temporal structure? i.e. if you display the gaze data sequentially, do you see narrow fixation clusters separated discontinuously by rapid saccadic jumps? Even better, plot the x and y channels independently as a function of time and look for the typical step-like pattern of saccades and fixations.